# игнорирование потомков родительского блока для события

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать событие `mouseover` на блок, но данное событие срабатывает и на всех детей этого узла, как можно проигнорировать всех детей которые находятся внутри блока. копал в сторону stopPropagation(), но так и не нарыл нужной имплементации.

```
<div id="test">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 // какая то логика 
},false);
```

И в данном случае `mouseout` срабатывает при наведении на класс `child`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
if(e.target.id == "test"){
// какая то логика 
}
},false);
```

Comment: `if(e.target.id != "test"){return;}` - зачем же все оборачивать в if

Comment: может дети понадобятся, тут же с ними и работать чуть что

Comment: ок , target.id != 'test', попадает на child и событие срабатывает

Comment: @dirk сорри, e.target.id надо, вот ссыль на пример http://plnkr.co/edit/nBqzN4z4yRDF6VUnx9Y2?p=preview

Comment: нарыл , что `mouseenter` игнорит детей, так же вариант